# How to download result directly from Design Automation?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am running a Design Automation job that generates an output.json file. Upon successful completion of the job, I would like to download directly that file without DA to store it on OSS or other cloud storage. All tutorials I can find seem to place the file on OSS. Direct download was doable with DA v1, do you happen to have an example for me?

Answer (score 2):

Direct download was doable with DA V2, no more with DA V3, you need to provide an upload storage URL, no other option for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this feature was discontinued because it muddied the data retention picture. DA V3 never retains your data beyond the conclusion of your workitem. DA V2 had a temporary storage for outputs.